# On a Linux system, how would I redirect stdout to stderr?

Tags: linux, stdout, stderr, output-redirect

I think its the case that you can't just assign the stdout *to* stderr because other things might have already cached (?) stdout by the time the reassignment takes place.

So how do I do this (using Linux)?

Comment: Any process already started has its standard output and standard error already determined.  It can change the settings; for practical purposes, you can't change its settings.  However, you can arrange for new processes to have stdout and stderr (note that they're single words, incidentally, not 'std out' and 'std err') go where you wish.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

To redirect the stdout to stderr, use your command as follows :-

```
$ command-name 1>&2
```

where `command-name` is the command you're going to feed, 1 represents `stdout` and 2 represents `stderr` .

Comment: 1 is default, so often `>&2` is used instead